# Splitting apart all grabbed links

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have the following code:

```
<div class="product">
     <div class="prod-img"><img src="#" /></div>
     <div class="prod-name">
          <a href="#">Product Name Here</a>
          <a href="#">Stuff we don't want to display</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
     <div class="prod-img"><img src="#" /></div>
     <div class="prod-name">
          <a href="#">Product Name Here</a>
          <a href="#">Stuff we don't want to display</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
     <div class="prod-img"><img src="#" /></div>
     <div class="prod-name">
          <a href="#">Product Name Here</a>
          <a href="#">Stuff we don't want to display</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

So I can use the following code to get all of the product names:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var products = $('.prod-name').find('a:first').text().trim();
    alert(products);
});
```

The problem is that it just shows all of the products in one giant string. Is there anyway I can separate these? with like a " | " or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.map()`

```
var products = $('.prod-name').find('a:first').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join('|');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/LGfj6/)

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks. I was looking into using .map but didn't really understand it. Thankyou so much I would have never figured this out on my own.